# error validating data: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

Error when I try to apply a `kubectl ou edit`, for `kubectl get pods`, it works normally.

"error validating data: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with `--validate=false`"

edit config and checked all pods on kube-system, all is working normally.

Answer (score 2):

I just found the problem, if you get this error, please check if your kubectl version is the same of server, my computer kubectl was in version v1.27.1 and server was v1.24.10, I used computer v1.24.10 as well and it worked fine!

kubectl version # it will show your computer and server version.

Answer (score 2):

For me this issue appeared with the latest helm version `3.12.0` running against a cluster with Kubernetes `1.24.10` and using kubectl version `1.27.1`.

```
  Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: error validating "": error validating data: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
```

I was first thinking it's an issue with the kubectl version, so I downgraded to earlier versions as mentioned in the answer from David, but that did not help.

The issue was caused by running `brew upgrade` on mac and I reverted to the older helm version `3.11.3` by running:

```
# unlink the current version
brew unlink helm
# download and install the version v3.11.3
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/1e9569bdecc40e762028cb441b8bfb7f595d3755/Formula/helm.rb && brew install ./helm.rb
```

This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

We use Terraform.
The issue was fixed after we got here and fixed our helm/kubectl version.

And 21 hours ago, [hashicorp/helm released 2.10](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest)...
The same issue happens again.

It took us a while to find it.
After fixing it at 2.9.0, everything works again.

Comment: The Kubectl version was already mentioned in the other answers.